# How to allow App to launch from Microsoft IE/Edge browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, uwp, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have AD authentication for my App, which opens the default browser for the App Authentication. After authentication, it prompts the user to launch the App via call back URL. This was working fine, but somehow it stops working. 
What I guess is that App launch permission got disabled in the browser settings. I cleared all the data but still, it's not prompting to launch the App. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you find some trace in event viewer? or in browser's debug console?

Comment: There are too many logs in the event viewer. Can you point me the event log that you are interested in?

Comment: by default, IE don't produce event log. Maybe [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie7_6-windows_xp/no-internet-explorer-entries-in-event-viewer-why/82c95d1e-27c5-4957-b181-1c1b4e926b22) is helpful? You can clear the event logs then re-run the app to see if new log entries are generated.

Comment: @kennyzx Sorry, the link that you mentioned is asking to change the registry which I can't do it. Is there any setting to reset App launch permission or reset browser settings completely?

Comment: What is the mean that "somehow it stops working"? Whether your uwp doesn't launch? Are you trying [Enable apps for websites using app URI handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking)? What are your app target version and the test device OS version?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I am not trying to implement any deep-linking feature. What I am trying to do is to just launch the App from the browser via callback URL, the same thing that happens when you click on any App in online Microsoft store and it tries to open App Store but in my case, it's from AD Authentication. While doing for the first time IE asked for a permission to allow launching the Application, but somehow now that permission got disabled.

Comment: How about calling the callback url in your browser? Will your app be launched every time? Does this issue only happen on the IE? How about the Edge?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Callback URL is called from the browser itself. I can't use Edge due to company policy settings